# The set $D_v=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^N: D_vf(x) \text{ exists } \}$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be Lipsticz function. The directional derivative in the direction of $\mathbf{v}$ is given by  $$ D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{x})=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{t}. $$ Define a set $$ D_\mathbf{v}=\{ \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n:D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{x})\text{ exists } \} .$$ Show that $D_\mathbf{v}$ is measurable.

Please help me in proving that.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Do you know that $\limsup_{t\to 0} g_t(x)$ of measurable functions for each $t$ is measurable?

Comment: Yes that I know. But how does this help could you please give me some more hint. Then probably I can proceed.

Comment: Then the set you are looking for is $\{x\ : \ \limsup_{t\to 0} g_t(x)-\liminf_{t\to 0}g_t(x)=0\} $ for a suitable chosen $g_t(x)$... Do you get it?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks.